# Error trying to logout: Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error when I try to logout an user. I checked many posts of this same error but no one solved my error, I hope you can help me.

The error is as follows:

```
    ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#destroy 
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_out
```

The following is my code:

users_controller.rb

```
    def destroy
      @user.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to unauthenticated_root_path }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
```

view/users/index.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
  </li>
```

routes.rb

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'admin/index'

  resources :contacts

  resources :afections

  resources :injuries

  resources :allergies

  resources :trainers

  resources :idusuarios

  resources :diseases

  resources :weights

  resources :diets

  resources :exercices

  resources :profiles

  resources :users

  devise_for :users

  get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'

  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      root 'pagina#index', as: :authenticated_root
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'` above `resources :users` in your routes. Routes are given priority in terms of their order in the routes file.

Comment: Solved! the routes.rb end like this: 
`get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  resources :users`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `resources :users` in your routes, you have this routes:

```
/users
/users/:id
/users/:id/edit
and ...
```

So when `/users/sign_out` is called, , thinks the `sign_out` is an ID.

so change `/users/sign_out` to `/user/sign_out` for example.

BUT

if you want customize your session paths, you can do this:

1. customize your session paths:

   ```
   as :user do
       get 'user/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
       post 'user/signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
       delete 'user/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session, via: [:delete, :get]
   end
   ```

and skip session in devise:

```
 devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
```

2. if you want user registration, you must skip it in devise and then  can use user scaffold:

   ```
   as :user do
       get 'user/signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
       post 'user/signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
       delete 'user/signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session, via: [:delete, :get]
   end
   scope "admin" do                
       resources :users 
       devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations]
   end
   ```